# How To Load Properties In A String Using configuration2.Configuration

Tags: java, apache

I'm migrating some modules from common configuration 1 to edition 2. In edition 1, I was able to properties from a string using this syntax

`propertiesConfiguration.load(stringReader);`

but I'm having difficulty figuring how to do this in version 2? Thanks in advance for any help with the above.

Comment: Version 2 of what?

Comment: Well, there is a migration guide... https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/upgradeto2_0.html

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for sending but I seen this already although I couldn't see details describing my use case above

Comment: Then I can't help either, never used commons-configuration :/.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it like this

```
PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration = new PropertiesConfiguration();
PropertiesConfigurationLayout propertiesConfigurationLayout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout();
propertiesConfigurationLayout.load(propertiesConfiguration,stringReader);
```

Hope this helps others.